# Import ArcPy in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, importerror

[image]
I am facing this problem how to fix it. How can I fix it? I already uninstall and reinstall numpy but that did not work.

Comment: Please post errors as text in the body of the question (images can't be indexed). You should probably reinstall ArcGIS entirely, since the install is corrupted.

Comment: You don't need to import arcpy in ArcMap.  It is already imported.  You only need to import it for stand-alone scripts run outside of ArcMap.  However, something is clearly wrong, as it should not generate an error if you re-import it.

Answer (score 2):

As [commented by @SonofaBeach](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353593/import-arcpy-in-arcmap/353607#comment579149_353593):

> You don't need to import arcpy in ArcMap. It is already imported. You
>   only need to import it for stand-alone scripts run outside of ArcMap.
>   However, something is clearly wrong, as it should not generate an
>   error if you re-import it.

I have resolved similar errors in the past by:

1. Using Windows Add/Remove Programs to uninstall ArcGIS Desktop
2. Deleting C:\Python27 - to remove anything missed by the ArcGIS Desktop uninstall - this may or may not be palatable to you
3. Reinstalling ArcGIS Desktop with a re-install of Python 2.x being part of that reinstall.

Also, as [commented by @MichaelStimson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353593/import-arcpy-in-arcmap/353607#comment579169_353607):

> The issue appears to be with numpy which should be installed with the
>   ArcGIS 10.x python 2.7 installer - perhaps this lib has been updated
>   (to an incompatible version) or removed or failed to install properly.
>   A repair reinstall should fix this and is bound to be less severe but
>   may not actually fix the problem unless numpy is missing, worth a shot
>   though IMO.

Comment: The issue appears to be with numpy which should be installed with the ArcGIS 10.x python 2.7 installer - perhaps this lib has been updated (to an incompatible version) or removed or failed to install properly. A repair reinstall should fix this and is bound to be less severe *but* may not actually fix the problem unless numpy is missing, worth a shot though IMO.